# Lazy loading of images with jQuery mysteriously works on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I have a website with lots of images, so it makes sense to lazy-load them. This is what my HTML looks like:

```
<div class="book-cell">
  <a class="book-cell" target="_blank" href="...">
    <figure>
      <picture>
        <source type="image/webp" data-srcset="/images/books/book-title.webp">
        <source type="image/png" data-srcset="/images/books/book-title.png">
        <img class="book-cell-cover" data-src="/images/books/book-title.png" alt="Book Title" width="205" height="356">
      </picture>
      <figcaption class="book-cell-caption"><i>Book Title</i> by Author</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
</div>
```

I load my scripts just before I close `<head>`:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.lazy/1.7.11/jquery.lazy.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.lazy/1.7.11/plugins/jquery.lazy.picture.min.js"></script>
```

Finally, I call on the jQuery libraries just before I close `</body>`:

```
<script src="/js/lazyload.js"></script>
```

This is the simple script inside:

```
$('.book-cell-cover').Lazy({
  effect: "fadeIn",
  effectTime: 500,
  threshold: 0
});
```

Everything works perfectly on desktop (here's a [demo](https://belovedbooksivegivenaway.ca#bibliography)), but on mobile, instead of fading in, the images so of all load and flash as I scroll by. The weird thing is, when I switch mobile Chrome to Desktop mode...it all works fine! What am I doing wrong?